Android Compose: how can i code a fullScreen Dialog(no statusbar)
I need to add a fullscreen blurred background to the dialog.
but I'm unable to hide the status bar or draw beneath it.
How should I resolve this?
Here's the code:
Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
        properties = DialogProperties(
            usePlatformDefaultWidth = false,
        ),
    ) {
        BlurBackground(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .clickable { onDismiss() }
        ) {...}
       }

I tried to user LocalView.current to get decorView，but fail

Finally, after trying a variety of methods, Dialog has never been able to spread the full screen, the second best thing to do is to turn off the gray semi-transparent background of the Dialog, by the Activity to display background images
Here's the code to turn off the Dialog's semi-transparent background.
LocalView.current.findWindow()
            ?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND 
              or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)
fun View.findWindow(): Window? =
    (parent as? DialogWindowProvider)?.window

